# How to pass information from content script to react component for chrome extensions?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a content script in my chrome extension that scrapes a couple values from the page. How would I go about sending the captured information down into React? I'm using a `v2` manifest. Any guidance would ber greatly appreciated.

I tried using `window.postMessage` to try and capture the data but I can't seem tto get it correctly recieve. Likely because the extension popup is different from the web page. Is there a better pattern for this?

Comment: Do it on demand as shown in [these examples](/a/67227376).